# How would I expand a superdiv with then scroll to a subdiv with scrollTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, user-interface

as you may have guessed from my post title I have no idea how to work with jQuery or javascript in general. I know that this isn't too hard of a function to put together but I can't seem to do it on my own.

Pretty much what I'm trying to do (in theory) is there are four large boxes that cover the available content area that link to (literal) menu items like breakfast, lunch, sides, and drinks hidden inside a div that when one of them is clicked the full menu expands down and scrolls gracefully down to the one they clicked on after which they can browse all the sections together as they please.

I have no idea how to do it and every time I try it breaks the page. Hopefully somebody with more than five minutes experence can help. I have no problem at all with CSS and HTML but scripting is just pitiful.

Comment: Show what you've got so far. Coding everything from skratch is possible, but not the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0):

So for scrolling you can do something like [this](http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/).

I don't quite understand how the full menu portion is supposed to work but you could hide it initially and then show it when the menu item link is clicked.